# Core Data cannot save data of UITextField in IOS Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode6

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "name"; 
desired type = NSString; given type = UITextField; value = 
<UITextField: 0x7fb13a63f7d0; frame = (39 246; 297 30); text = 
myworld'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fb13a71f740>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb13a63fa80>>.'

 First throw call stack:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da88c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d71fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreData                            0x000000010cf208a3 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 3203
3   CoreData                            0x000000010cef92f1 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 177
4   MyStore                             0x000000010ce2b2f7 -[DetailViewController save:] + 183
5   UIKit                               0x000000010de83d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x000000010de83d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
7   UIKit                               0x000000010df9550a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
8   UIKit                               0x000000010df948d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
9   UIKit                               0x000000010ded0958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
10  UIKit                               0x000000010ded1282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
11  UIKit                               0x000000010de97541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
12  UIKit                               0x000000010dea4cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
13  UIKit                               0x000000010de7f59c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d9bc431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d9b22fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d9b1934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d9b1366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110feaa3e GSEventRunModal + 161
19  UIKit                               0x000000010de828c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
20  MyStore                             0x000000010ce2b07f main + 111
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110156145 start + 1
22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3):

As per crash report error is telling you, the value you are giving is a UITextField instead of textfield.text i.e of NSString for "name" property

For Similar issue you can refer here 
 [unacceptable-type-of-value-for-attribute-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029327/unacceptable-type-of-value-for-attribute-property)